# Oracle run report on SQL Server error, installed ODAC still have error

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a Oracle database version 12.1.0.2.0 that running on SQL Server SSRS 2016.

When I run the report, it pops the below error.

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ORACLE' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsDataExtensionNotFound)

Then I have installed the package called "ODAC122011_x64" on it , but still no help .

Would advise how to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Not what version, what edition? Express? Web? Standard? Enterprise? Something else?

Comment: SQL Server 2016  Enterprise